# how can i get EXPOSURE TIME when i take picture using camera2?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

Hello I use android camera 2 and I want to get the exposure time when my picture is saved without Exif interface.

It's possible to get this value ? How do that ?

I try many time but the result is `0`

There is my code:

```
public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME)));

    createCameraPreview();
}
```

I put this code on captureComplete I think it's the best place to get this value.

thanks!

Comment: Check in `CaptureResult`, there are couple of keys that seem useful, such as [SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME)

Comment: thanks @M.Prokhorov I use CaptureResult instead of CaptureRequest I get the result in nano seconds Thanks ! like : `Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `CaptureResult` instead of `CaptureRequest`. You can see how in the example below:

```
public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
     super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME)));

     createCameraPreview();
}
```